# Excel file size reduces to half when resaved

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, reporting-services

We have few reports in SSRS. When i try to download the reports from SSRS server site as excel file i.e. lets say i downloaded the file from server site to a location as excel(file) it consumes 1000 kb but when i try to re-save it (without any changes just re-saving using save as) the excel file size actually reduces to half of it to 500 kb. Does any of you have the same issue if so please advise me on how to efficiently import the reports to excel file.

Thank you

Comment: So when you resave the excel file, the excel file is half as large?  Is it loosing data when you resave it or is the file size just changing.  If you are saving from a .xls file to a .xlsx or .xlsb then the size will be reduced.  If you are saving from a .xlsx to .xlsb the size will also be reduced.  Is anything like that happening?

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: Hey @Jarom,There is no difference in data except the file size changes when i just open the file and re-save it from 1000 kb to 500 kb when i re-save it

Comment: Hey @Mat'sMug,I am using visual studio 2012

Comment: how are you determining the file size?

Comment: Are you resaving the opened file (or) from the report ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be deploying your reports to a version of SQL Server (possibly 2008R2) that still renders .XLS (Excel 2003) instead of .XLSX (Excel 2007+). We have seen this behaviour before. It is a known issue [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-excel-report-builder-and-ssrs).

> Sizes of Excel 2003 (.xls) Files
>
> Important
>   The Microsoft Excel 2003 rendering extension is deprecated. For more information, see Deprecated Features in SQL Server Reporting Services in SQL Server 2016.
>
> When reports are first exported and saved to Excel 2003, they do not benefit from the file optimization that Excel automatically applies to its .xls workbook files. The larger file size can cause problems for e-mail subscriptions and attachments. To reduce the size of the .xls files for exported reports, open the *.xls files and then resave the workbooks. Resaving the workbooks typically reduces their file sizes by 40 to 50 percent.

This is resolvable by upgrading to a later version of SQL which renders to .XLSX. If using SharePoint as a host you may need to upgrade SharePoint to a an [appropriate version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/supported-combinations-of-sharepoint-and-reporting-services-server).

Comment: i created an excel sheet with python xlsxwriter. When i resaved it with libreoffice calc the size decreased by more than 60 percent. why is it ?

Comment: See the "according to Microsoft" link in my answer and read the section "Sizes of Excel 2003 (.xls) Files". It mentions that there is a file optimization not used by the SSRS XLS renderer. This may also be the case with python xlswriter I guess. Opening and resaving in Excel or libreoffice calc must both apply the file optimization. Note: I have never used either of those applications.